# Issue connecting to rabbitmq from container

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04

I am having an issue connecting to a **rabbitmq server**. I can connect to it from the host machine but I cannot get a connection from the container. It used to work before I've upgraded my **Ubuntu to 16.04**.

Please help.

Comment: Is your container still running? `docker ps --all`?

Comment: Yes It is running.

Comment: Please add more details. The docker image you are using and the docker run command you are using is the bare minimum.

Comment: I'm a total beginner to this. please let me know what details you need. I use "docker-compose up" to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer finally. it's a new feature since the version 3.3.0 , It's preventing access using the default guest/guest credentials except via localhost as mentioned [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt).

Comment: One of my life saver ... Thanks @suzo

Comment: @suzo Can I ask the commands you use to connect the two containers together? I am having no success doing so.